# Java Android: how to get pixel color at position (X, Y) of GLSurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, arcore, glsurfaceview

I have a android.opengl.GLSurfaceView (in a ARCore project)

I want to get the color of a pixel at the position (X, Y) of this view.

How can I do that ? (in the most efficient way because I will do that many times per frame)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There is no efficient way to do such task. The reason is that since [GLSurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView) performs the rendering with OpenGL, the pixel must be retrieved from the GPU. Not forgetting that the retreival must be done within the actual GLSurfaceView rendering thread. You can access its render thread, via the [renderer listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer), the best option is the [onDrawFrame](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer#onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10)) callback.

To get a specific pixel (or all pixels), use the [glReadPixels](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20#glReadPixels(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.nio.Buffer)) method. You can specify at which x/y coordinates and the amount of pixels by width/height.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4); // 4 = (1 width) * (1 height) * (4 as per RGBA)
GLES20.glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

When retrieving a specific coordinate, take into consideration the **upside-down nature of OpenGL**.

Notice that **glReadPixels** is notoriously slow in many devices. Not an issue if is for a simple one time request, but to be taken into consideration if you must call it nonstop.